# Inno Setup - display warning page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Script Studio to build an installer, so far very successfully as Inno Setup is a great package.

However, I want to add a warning page which is displayed when the user unchecks an important Task. I thought this would just be an easy check. After some Googling, I realised that this will require some Pascal scripting - something that I unfortunately have no knowledge of (evidence below)...

```
begin
  if not IsTaskSelected('ImportantTask') then
    WarningPage := CreateOutputMsgPage(wpSelectTasks, 'Caution',
    'Please read the following important information before continuing.',
    'You have not selected the ImportantTask option. Click "Back" to
    reselect ImportantTask, or click "Next" to continue at your own risk.');
  end;
```

Unsurprisingly, this didn't work.

---

Here are the requirements:

- **ImportantTask** is to be checked by default.
- If **ImportantTask** is *unselected* then display **WarningPage** with *Risk Acknowledgement* checkbox.
- If risk acknowledgement checkbox is unticked, disable the **Next** button.

I didn't want to end up with a large [Code] section, but there is possibly no other option.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use msgbox's instead wizard pages. Msgbox's are especially used for Giving any indication(info,warning..etc) to user..
This script works as per your requirement.

```
[Setup]
AppName=MySetup 
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\MySetup 
[Tasks]
Name: "ImportantTask"; Description: "This task should be selected"; GroupDescription: "Important tasks";
[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) and not IsTaskSelected('ImportantTask') then
    Result := Msgbox('You have not selected the ImportantTask option.' + #13#10 + 
      'Are you sure you want to continue ?', mbInformation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES;
end;
```

credit goes to TLama...

Comment: thank you! - that's great. Good idea to use the message box too, as it's a sure-fire way to get the user's attention.  
I modified your code to have an `else Result := True;` if the `CurPageID` was not `wpSelectTasks`, because I have a few other pages in my setup file.

Comment: Here is [`a fix for the above script`](http://pastebin.com/mJzvxd5S). There are few things to note. There's no need for so many `if` conditions for result, which always evaluates to True. Just set it to True at the beginning of the method. I guess you wanted to stay on the page when the user answers the dialog with `IDNO`, which is not here. And the usage of the `IsTaskSelected` function was correct. You should not rely on fixed indexes. And finally, line break is `#13#10`, not only `#13` ;-)

Comment: @TLama thank you very much for giving such a nice explanation..,I have seen your two methods of code...second method is very impressive........